# Could not find method plugins() for arguments on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\eskuul_app\android\build.gradle' line: 7

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method plugins() for arguments [build_f2rrostxp7qge0zdoomgbff4k$_run_closure1$_closure3@1d093885] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1[my gradle.build[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ketEY.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNMCm.png)
```

I was trying to migrate my Firebase account to another one when I lost contact with my developer who connected it from his side in the first place. I went through all the processes Firebase instructed me to but I am still having this issue. Can anyone please help with this what might be the problem?